# Views Data Export, exports entire HTML of page

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I have added the Data Export module.

I have a View creating a Page of fields into a table. Filtered by Content Type, Published, and an 'exposed' (User set) item relevant to the content type, and a Flag (with Flag module) setting (exposed as well).

I have set the Data export with the same fields to export a CSV, attached to the page.
When I click the CSV icon I get a CSV download that contains all the HTML of my page, NOT the table.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "all the HTML" do you mean all nodes  (i.e. not filtered by content type, flag, etc)?

Comment: No, I mean the whole page as if I am looking at page source.

Comment: Either you should file a bugreport (if there are no customizations by you), or provide more details to this question.

Comment: And you using the module Views Data Export? Not Views Datasource, right?